# CoreData dynamically create db

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, osx-lion, osx-mavericks

I want to create app where you can add projects and save them in CoreData. 
For every project the app should create separate **.sqlite** file.
How can I achieve that?
My idea is to  `NSManagedObject` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` for every project, is this good approach?

Comment: Why do you want separate persistent stores for each project?

Comment: Because I will make simultaneous many crud operations in this persistent stores and want keep them independent.

Comment: download iProjectFree for Mac or iOS. It uses UIManagedDocument on iOS and NSPersistentDocument on OS X and supports multiple documents.

Comment: You're better off keeping them together. Also, look into `UIManagedDocument` or `NSPersistentDocument`, as @DuncanGroenewald suggested.

Comment: If you want to get some insight into UIManagedDocument & iCloud Integration try this link http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/